# force node.exe to go throw proxifier on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, proxy, telegram, vpn

I am developing [bots](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) for [telegram](https://telegram.me/), I am from Iran and telegram url is blocked in my country and I am forced to use VPN/Proxy servers to access telegram api from my local dev machine.

But I have other apps running on my system that won't work throw a VPN, So I am forced to use [proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/), I can define rules for the apps that I need to go throw a proxy.

But node.exe is ignoring this rules for some reason, I can see in [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/) that the connection is coming from `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe`, But adding this path to proxifier's rules has no effect, other apps like telegram itself and firefox and ... works fine with these rules ...

So has anyone managed to force node.exe to go throw proxifier?

I also tried to setup a proxcy with php in my host, but none of the proxy scripts I found was able to handle the file uploads

My last hope is to install some modules for apache and use it as a proxy or just install nginx ...

I also tried https://github.com/krisives/proxysocket and https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent with no success, its just keeps throwing errors :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after hours of trying finally got this to work with proxifier.

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent

`new HttpsProxyAgent('http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8080')`

---

Update :
This approach had its problems so I created a small personal proxy server with [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) on my server and connected to it:

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;

const debug     = require('debug')('app');
const http      = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  secure : false
});
proxy.on('error', function (e) {
  debug(e);
});

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // You can define here your custom logic to handle the request
  // and then proxy the request.
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'https://api.telegram.org', });
});

server.listen(3333);
```

And simply just redirected all the request to this server.